# Delete reply button is happening for 1 time only unless i refresh the page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a comment form whith each comment has replies. I manage to program the system that when a new comment is submitted using ajax php and jquery the comment shows in the list of the replies. Now I am programming the delete reply button also with ajax php and jquery. What is happening is that when i refresh the page, i can delete the reply comment of the first delete button that i click ! and after that when i click on delete for another reply comment, nothing happens. Then if i reload the page i can delete another reply comment that i click on but no more than one reply after each refresh. I need your help please to be able to delete more than one reply without refreshing the page

I will post the codes next for jquery and ajax please let me know if other codes are needed

here is my jquery and ajax codes for the delete button :

```js
// Delete a reply
$('.delete_board_reply_button').click(function() {
  var deleteReplyButtonParent = $(this).attr("id");
  var idArray = deleteReplyButtonParent.split("-");
  var boardReplyId = idArray[0];
  //console.log(boardReplyId);
  var url = "widgets/delete_board_reply.php";

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      reply_id: boardReplyId
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // here i make a custom pop up alert
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(jqXHR);
    }
  });

  var commentId_attr = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
  var commentArray = commentId_attr.split("-");
  var boardCommentId = commentArray[0];
  console.log(boardCommentId);
  loadBoardReplies(boardCommentId);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reply_comment_div" id="<?php echo $reply_id;?>-boardReplyDelete">
  <a href="profile.php?user_id=<?php echo (int)$reply_user_id;?>" class="board_comments_div_picture">
       <img src="
       <?php 
        $profile_image = $reply_user_data['profile_picture']; 
        $profile_image_thumb = "uploaded_pictures/profile/$reply_user_id/" . $reply_user_id . "small.png";
        
        if ($profile_image == "") {
         if ($comment_user_data['gender'] == "Male"){
          echo "images/ProfilePicMale.png";
         } else {
          echo "images/ProfilePicFemale.png";
         }
        } else {
         echo $profile_image_thumb;
        }
       
       
        ?>" width="50px" height="50px" alt="" title=""/>
      </a>

  <a href="profile.php?user_id=<?php echo (int)$reply_user_id;?>" class="board_comments_reply_link">
    <?php echo ucfirst(htmlentities($reply_user_data['first_name'])) . " " . ucfirst(htmlentities($reply_user_data['last_name']));?>
  </a>
  <?php 
      if ($user_id == $_SESSION['user_id']){ 
     ?>
  <a href="edit_comment_board.php?comment_id=<?php echo $reply_comment_id;?>" class="edit_comment_button_board">Edit</a>
  <input type="button" class="delete_board_reply_button" value="Delete" name="delete_board_reply_button" id="<?php echo $reply_id;?>-replyId" />
  <?php 
      }
     ?>
  <div class="board_comment_submited_on">
    submitted
    <?php echo time_of_post($reply_timestamp);?>
  </div>
  <span class="comment_content_span"><?php echo nl2br($reply_text);?></span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
I did some investigating pasting line by line for the delete Button jquery codes So what i found is that the problem occurs when I add this line

```
loadBoardReplies(boardCommentId);
```

Which refer to this function :

```
    function loadBoardReplies (value) {
    var url = "widgets/board_reply_fetch.php";

    $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            comment_id: value
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#"+value+"-").html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    });
}
```

But i can't seem to tell what the problem is for now ! if i comment this line, i am able to delete any reply i want except the replies won't update and the deleted reply will stay appeared in the DOM

Comment: Have you verified that the ids are being generated correctly in the markup?

Comment: yes i did, i checked the page source and each id is being generated where it is supposed to

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about this?

```
var commentId_attr = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
```

It seems `$(this).parent() == <div>` in that HTML structure. Have you tried with that?

Regards

Comment: yes I am sure, the thing is that after i refresh the page, the first reply i click on from any of the comments gets deleted but no more than 1 reply per comment. this : `var commentId_attr = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");` gives me back the Id of the comment on which i am replying, so the parent().parent() will give comment Id and (this).attr("id") will give the reply id itself of the delete button that i clicked on, it will give only 1 element because it is an idea and only 1 element with this id exists so my logic seems right but what it is letting me click delete for only 1 reply/com